# Using gekko for large scale dynamic flowsheet simulation with custom thermodynamics and flash algorithms

Tags: python, gekko

I am evaluating different tools to solve dynamic flowsheets of chemical processes. At the moment I am using my python implementation of a sequential steady state solver where I have a combination of compressors, flash separators, mixers, splitters etc.

The thermodynamic properties and vapor/liquid equilibrium is solved using Peng-Robinson using different mixing rules.

The flash algorithms are basically nested loops using newtons algorithm to solve the equilibrium constrains by fixing pressure-temperature, pressure-enthalpy, volume-temperature etc.

The units basically solve the mass and energy balance by calling a flash routine. In some instances such as the splitter there are conditionals such as if the pressure at the inlet or outlet has a certain value set the flow rate of an output port to a certain value.

My idea is to transfer all my python code of the units, thermodynamics and flash algorithms to Gekko objects so I can use them in different simulations.

Even though there are some posts similar to this question, all of them consider using an external thermodynamic library such as Coolprop and Refprop. In my case I want to program the thermodynamics myself.

I have looking at all the gekko documentation but so far it is not clear for me if it is possible to implement the conditionals inside the units (such as controlling the outlet based on a condition), programming a cubic equation of state and solving the flash algorithms.

I am sure if I can add the EoS and the flash algorithms the dynamic solution of the flowsheet integrating units, thermodynamics and flashes would be possible.

Any thoughts, recommendations or starting points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional statements are possible with binary switch variables using the `if3()` function or MPCCs (continuous, non-integer variables) using the `if2()` function. However, these logical conditions can be challenging to solve. Here are three potential suggestions:

1. Include the EOS or other equations with bounds and initial guess values to determine the liquid or vapor solution. Below is an example with Scipy fsolve and gekko using the Redlich/Kwong Equation of State:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# constants
TC = 77 # degC
P = 1.0 # bar
a = 2.877e8 # cm^6 bar K^0.5 / mol^2
b = 60.211  # cm^3 / mol
Rg = 83.144598 # cm^3 bar / K-mol
# derived quantities
TK = TC+273.15 # K
Vg = Rg*TK/P # ideal gas guess

# Scipy fsolve solution
def f(V):
    return P-Rg*TK/(V-b) + a/(np.sqrt(TK)*V*(V+b))
V = fsolve(f,Vg)
print(f'Scipy Vapor Solution: {V[0]:0.1f} cm^3/mol')
V = fsolve(f,b*1.1)
print(f'Scipy Liquid Solution: {V[0]:0.1f} cm^3/mol')

# Gekko solutions
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
V = m.Var(value=Vg,lb=1e4)
m.Equation(P == Rg*TK/(V-b) - a/(np.sqrt(TK)*V*(V+b)))
m.options.SOLVER=1; m.solve(disp=False)
print(f'Gekko Vapor Solution: {V.value[0]:0.1f} cm^3/mol')
# update bounds and initial guess
V.lower=b*0.5; V.upper = b*2; V.value=b*1.1
m.options.SOLVER=1; m.solve(disp=False)
print(f'Gekko Liquid Solution: {V.value[0]:0.1f} cm^3/mol')
```

They both produce the two correct solutions:

```
Scipy Vapor Solution: 28638.7 cm^3/mol
Scipy Liquid Solution: 82.5 cm^3/mol
Gekko Vapor Solution: 28638.7 cm^3/mol
Gekko Liquid Solution: 82.5 cm^3/mol
```

2. Gekko has a limited number of objects that assist with modeling flowsheet applications through the APMonitor modeling language. Below is an example of a [distillation column](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/DistillationColumn).

```
! APMonitor Modeling Language
! http://www.apmonitor.com

! Distillation column
Compounds
 ethylene 
 propylene
 propane
 nitrogen
 hydrogen
End Compounds

Model distill
  Objects
   ! feed stream
   feed           = Feed
   feed_lag       = Stream_Lag
   feed_cooler    = Vessel
   feed_flash     = Flash
   liq_mixer      = Mixer
   vap_mixer      = Mixer

   ! condenser and reflux
   condenser      = Vessel
   drum           = Flash
   reflux         = Splitter

   ! column stages
   stage[1:8]     = Stage_1

   ! reboiler
   sump           = Vessel
   reboiler       = Vessel
   reboiler_flash = Flash

   ! mass and massflows
   sump_mass      = Mass
   !feed_massflow  = Massflow
   cleu_massflow  = Massflow
   btms_massflow  = Massflow
  End Objects

  Connections
   ! feed streams
   feed.*                      = feed_lag.inlet.*
   feed_lag.outlet.*           = feed_cooler.inlet.*
   feed_cooler.outlet.*        = feed_flash.inlet.*
   feed_flash.outlet_vap.*     = vap_mixer.inlet[1].*
   feed_flash.outlet_liq.*     = liq_mixer.inlet[1].*

   ! liquid down the column
   liq_mixer.inlet[2].*        = stage[1].l_out.*
   liq_mixer.outlet.*          = stage[2].l_in.*
   stage[2:7].l_out.*          = stage[3:8].l_in.*
   stage[8].l_out.*            = sump.inlet.*

   ! reboiler
   sump.outlet.*               = reboiler.inlet.*
   reboiler.outlet.*           = reboiler_flash.inlet.*

   ! vapor up the column
   reboiler_flash.outlet_vap.* = stage[8].v_in.*
   stage[3:8].v_out.*          = stage[2:7].v_in.*
   vap_mixer.inlet[2].*        = stage[2].v_out.*
   vap_mixer.outlet.*          = stage[1].v_in.*

   ! condenser
   stage[1].v_out.*            = condenser.inlet.*
   condenser.outlet.*          = drum.inlet.*
   drum.outlet_liq.*           = reflux.inlet.*
   reflux.outlet[2].*            = stage[1].l_in.*

   ! mass and massflow meters
   sump.reserve.*              = sump_mass.acc.*
   !feed.*                      = feed_massflow.stream.*
   drum.outlet_vap.*           = cleu_massflow.stream.*
   reboiler_flash.outlet_liq.* = btms_massflow.stream.*

   ! stream pressures
   strm_p                      = stage[1].v_out.p
   strm_p                      = stage[2:8].l_out.p
   strm_p                      = stage[3:8].v_out.p

   ! feed and stage pressures
   fd_p                        = stage[1:8].l_res.p
  End Connections

  Parameters
     fd_t     = 370.0  ! K
     fd_p     = 3.11e6 ! Pa
     fd_c2h4  = 0.28   ! mol%
     fd_c3h6  = 0.6184 ! mol%
     fd_c3h8  = 0.0916 ! mol%
     fd_h2    = 0.01   ! mol%

     strm_p   = fd_p   ! Pa
  End Parameters

  Variables
     fd_ndot  = 1.0
     !fd_mdot  = 0.395  ! kg/sec
  End Variables

  Connections
     fd_t     = feed.t
     fd_p     = feed.p
     fd_c2h4  = feed.x[1]
     fd_c3h6  = feed.x[2]
     fd_c3h8  = feed.x[3]
     fd_h2    = feed.x[4]
     !fd_mdot  = feed_massflow.mdot
     fd_ndot  = feed.ndot
  End Connections

  Intermediates
  End Intermediates

  Equations
  End Equations

End Model
```

This flowsheet capability is not fully integrated into the Gekko platform, so it may be better to write the equations yourself.

3. Use functions to simplify the model coding. Below is a function test from the [GEKKO GitHub examples](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/tree/master/examples) (`test_function.py`).

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

def f(x,c):
    y = m.sum([(xi-c)**2 for xi in x])
    return y

x1 = m.Array(m.Var,5)
p  = 2.1

m.Minimize(f(x1,p))
m.Equation(f(x1,0)<=10)
m.solve()

print(x1)
```